# Accordion with Open / Close Arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to get this accordion effect for my website:

http://bootsnipp.com/brojask/snippets/Q6zjv#comments

I have directly copyed the code to my code, but the Script seems not to be working, because the arrow does not change from down to up side.

Here is my code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="quienes_somos.aspx.cs" Inherits="xxxxxxxxxxx.acerca_de.quienes_somos" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" runat="server">
<script language="javascript"  type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on('show','.accordion', function (e) {
         //$('.accordion-heading i').toggleClass(' ');
         $(e.target).prev('.accordion-heading').addClass('accordion-opened');
    });

    $(document).on('hide','.accordion', function (e) {
        $(this).find('.accordion-heading').not($(e.target)).removeClass('accordion-opened');
        //$('.accordion-heading i').toggleClass('fa-chevron-right fa-chevron-down');
    });
</script>
<style>
.accordion-toggle:after {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content: "\e114"; 
    float: right;
}
.accordion-opened .accordion-toggle:after {   
    content: "\e113";    
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Accordion with Open / Close Arrows</h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
<div class="accordion-group">
<div class="accordion-heading">
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
Collapsible Group Item #1
</a>
</div>
<div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
<div class="accordion-inner">
Anim pariatur cliche...
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-group">
<div class="accordion-heading">
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
Collapsible Group Item #2
</a>
</div>
<div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
<div class="accordion-inner">
Anim pariatur cliche...
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Could someone help me solving this issue? Thank you in advance ;-)

Comment: can you create a fiddle please?

Comment: Hi messerbill, here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/javozan/ew5co2em/

Comment: I tryed with this new accordeon, but the sections do not slide as they do in Fiddle. It looks like my page does not read the script. http://jsfiddle.net/nandhakumarsri9/gu7h3/7/